# How to create multiple Stenciljs components with slight differences?

Tags: stenciljs

I wrote a Stenciljs component "textarea" with a lot of methods and logic. Additionally I need an inputfield with pretty much the same functionality but some minor differences. I don't want to maintain two components that have nearly the same tests, nearly the same styles and nearly the same methods that would end in a lot of code duplicates.

Right now i created a generic component "idb-input" with a "type" property that can be "textarea" or "textfield" and use if else statements to decide which methods are allowed for this type. Since this is a bit messy i would like to have a "base component" and inheritate from it for example. I already tried to use a generic typescript class but i can't use the decorators and a lot more limitations.

Further this approach isn't that clean in HTML:

```
<idb-input type="textarea">
<idb-input type="numberfield">
<idb-input type="inputfield">
```

What is the right way solving this problem?